# What is the difference between initializing shared_ptr with just another pointer and initializing it with the get method?

Tags: c++

There is a `process` function:

```
void process(std::shared_ptr<int> sh_ptr) {}
```

What is the difference between the two `process` function calls?

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42));
// process(std::shared_ptr<int>(p));
// process(std::shared_ptr<int>(p.get()));
```

Can you explain what exactly happens in both calls?
I can't figure out what the `get` method is for

**My thoughts:**
As I understand it, the first call to the `process` function passes it a temporary pointer shared_ptr, which points to int, just like the `p` pointer. Inside the process function the counter will be 2, after leaving the function, `p` will be the only pointer and the counter will be 1. Everything seems to be correct. Correct me if I'm wrong

What happens in the second case is not clear to me and I'd like to figure it out.

Comment: What does "cannot compile code correctly" mean? What does "can't figure out what the `get` method is for " mean, doesn't your C++ textbook, in the same chapter that talks about `shared_ptr`, explain what `get()` does, and how it works?

Comment: The second case is is wrong and will result in deleting the int object twice. There is no point wasting time on it, just avoid doing it.

Comment: When you do `std::shared_ptr<int>(p.get())`, what happens to the memory once the new shared pointer object is destructed? What happens with the pointer that `p` is pointing to? Remember that you will have two different and distinct `shared_ptr` objects, but that both are pointing to the same memory which is *not* shared between them.

Comment: It calls two different construcotrs, one from another shared_pointer, one from a raw pointer. No. 8 vs. No. 3 here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr. They both work, but have different implications about ownership of that pointer.

Comment: The second creates a *new* owner of the shared object, but that new `shared_ptr` believes that it is the only owner of that object, and will destroy it when it's done with it. The already existing owner(s) of the shared object will be very confused when it doesn't exist any more. (I find that it helps to not think of the "smart pointers" as pointers at all, because they aren't.)

Comment: compiles for me: https://godbolt.org/z/cEYEsrMqG please provide a [mre] and the full error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets illustrate it:

You create a pointer to an `int` value:

```
int* p1 = new int(some_value);
```

That will look something like this:

```
+----+      +------------------+
| p1 | ---> | int (some_value) |
+----+      +------------------+
```

Then what you're doing is creating a second pointer, initialized to point to the same location:

```
int* p2 = p1;
```

That will then look something like this:

```
+----+
| p1 | -\
+----+  |    +------------------+
         >-> | int (some_value) |
+----+  |    +------------------+
| p2 | -/
+----+
```

This is really what happens when you do `shared_ptr<int>(p.get())`.

Now lets delete the second pointer:

```
delete p2;
```

This deletion is what happens when the temporary shared object is destructed. And that leaves you with this:

```
+----+      
| p1 | ---> ???
+----+
```

because the memory allocated for `p1` was deleted using `p2`.

---

With your code you create two distinct and different pointers, that both point to the same memory but which don't share any state. Both the smart pointers will think they have exclusive ownership of the memory, and they don't know anything about each other.

---

At a *very* simplified level, the shared pointer and its `get` function is working something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class shared_ptr
{
public:
    shared_ptr() = default;  // Defaulted default constructor

    shared_ptr(T* raw);  // Constructor using raw pointers
        : raw_{ raw }    // Example usage: shared_ptr<int> p(new int)
    {
    }

    T* get()
    {
        return raw_;  // Returns the raw pointer
    }

private:
    T* raw_ = nullptr;  // The actual raw pointer
};
```

The `get` function simply returns the raw unmanaged pointer. Any construction using such a raw unmanaged pointer will simply copy the pointer itself, as there's no information about ownership or that it's part of another shared pointer.

Comment: Thx. But I still don't really understand how `get` method itself works. What does it return when called? According to the description it should return a pointer to an object, but `p` itself is a pointer, isn't it? If `p` and `p.get()` are called, the same addresses will be returned. This confuses me and I can't understand why the results are different in both cases of calling the process function. In the first case you get 2 pointers with the same counter, and in the second case you get 2 independent pointers with their own counters to the same memory.

Comment: @iamnotevg `p` is *not* a pointer, it's an instance of a class. `p.get()` is a pointer; it is a pointer to the object that `p` owns (and shares with other members of its "sharing community").

Comment: @iamnotevg Added a ***very*** simplified example of how the `get` function is implemented, together with the corresponding raw pointer constructor. It's a little more complicated than that but should hopefully get the point (pun not intended) across.